# Removing a window style after the window's creation

Tags: c++, winapi, styles, window

I have created a window with the following code:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

The window has the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style at the creation time, but I want to remove this style if a button is clicked. I saw [reference for `SetWindowLong()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't know how to use it in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style states:

> To add or remove this style, use the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

So, clearly you can't use `SetWindowLong` to clear this style.

Try:

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: if  you help me with that line of code (because I am a beginner) I will mark your answer as the one for this question

Comment: thank you. it is working fine. now I will try on my own to make my program to be able to toggle the topmost style for the window.

Comment: If `HWND_NOTOPMOST` doesn't do it, try another `hWndInsertAfter` value like `HWND_TOP`.

Comment: A closing remark: Microsoft's API references are usually notoriously comprehensive. You should pick up the habit of reading about every API function that you use and every single argument those functions take. You won't be disappointed. Second remark: Don't trust anyone. Read the reference yourself (if you're copying some code off some blog etc.).